# How do I track traffic from TikTok with IONOS?

Tags: links, social-media

I've got a channel on TikTok with over 8,000 followers and over 350,000 views.

My URL is in the profile but I don't see traffic referred by TicTok in IONOS > Referring pages.

How can I figure out how much traffic I'm getting from my TikTok profile link?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Ionos, is that some sort of analytics?  When I search for it, I get lots of results for 1&1 Ionos which is a hosting company.

Comment: @MarcBolh Seems Ionos also has a website builder platform.  Assuming I am right, is there a way to integrate Google Analytics?

Comment: Yes, Ionos is a hosting company that provides website traffic referral data.

Comment: I checked Google Analytics > All Website Data > Referrals but didn't see anything for TikTok.

Comment: Check if the link tag in tiktok has a noreferrer attribute (rel=”noreferrer”) added to it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up a UTM link to put in your bio to be able to track referrals to your site.

[UTM parameters in campaign tracking - IONOS](https://www.ionos.com/digitalguide/online-marketing/web-analytics/utm-parameters-explained/)